# SIGSEGV in __lll_unlock_wake_private

Tags: segmentation-fault, gdb

when I use function fread, the program gets error with  __lll_unlock_wake_private getting sigsegv, the gdb messages are as following:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()          
#1  0x009b77b6 in __lll_unlock_wake_private () from /lib/libc.so.6         
#2  0x00931c3b in _L_unlock_134 () from /lib/libc.so.6                   
#3  0x00931bd8 in fread () from /lib/libc.so.6              
#4  0x08049654 in init_global_list () at main.c:235                    
#5  0x0804b4e9 in init_prog () at main.c:1085                  
#6  0x0804c53f in main (argc=1, argv=0xf0) at main.c:1591
```

I want to know how the function __lll_unlock_wake_private works?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how the function __lll_unlock_wake_private works?

You can see its source [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/lowlevellock.S;hb=b987917e6aa7ffe2fd74f0b6a989438e6edd0727#l332).

But the most likely reason you got a `SIGSEGV` is that you called `fread` with `NULL` stream parameter.

If you execute the following `gdb` commands: `frame 4`, `list`, you should be able to see the call site, and see what values you passed into `fread`.